# Set videojs volume by external and custom toolbar

Tags: html, jquery, video.js

I have a video (I am using videojs) and an external toolbar.
The toolbar has the volume icon. I save the value of the volume in the session storage.

In the controller of videojs I wrote this code:

```
$(window).bind('storage', function(e)
{
...
var vp = videojs('player').player();
vp.volume = sessionStorage.getItem('customVolume');
...
```

but it doesn't work :(

Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

`volume` is a function not a property. `player()` is not necessary here.

```js
var vp = videojs('player');
vp.volume(sessionStorage.getItem('customVolume'));
```